# Puntos y comas en Golang, ¿Recomendado a nivel de rendimiento?

Tags: optimización, compilador, go, lenguaje-compilado

Sé que no es requerido el uso de ; en GOlang, pero para el compilador de Golang que es más eficiente, ¿que lo pongamos o no?

Comment: Seamos honestos. "Más eficiente" es muy relativo... ganar 100 milisegundos subre una compilacion que dura 5 segundos contra un humano que la corre en su máquina local no justifica rellenar un código de puntos y comas.. .|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fuente: https://nachopacheco.gitbooks.io/go-es/content/doc/go-eficiente/index.html#puntos-y-comas

> Como en C, la gramática formal de Go usa puntos y comas para terminar declaraciones, pero a diferencia de C, esos puntos y comas no aparecen en la fuente. En su lugar el analizador léxico al escanear la fuente utiliza una sencilla regla para insertar puntos y comas automáticamente, así que de entrada, el texto mayoritariamente está libre de ellos.
>
> El analizador léxico siempre inserta un punto y coma después del símbolo. Esto se podría resumir como, “si la nueva línea viene después de un segmento que pudiera acabar una declaración, inserta un punto y coma”.

Es decir, el punto y coma lo añade el analizador léxico, y según he leído en varias fuentes, no se pone el punto y coma para hacer el código más limpio, puedes ver que los paquetes de go (¿C:/Go/src?) no lo llevan.

Además, gofmt elimina los puntos y comas del código cuando estás programando Go en Visual Studio, por ejemplo, por lo que, sea mejor o no para el compilador, las bases de Go "estipulan" que no hay que ponerlo.

También puedes leer https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/XuMrWI0Q8uk para más información.